# JMeter Regular Expression Extractor to extract custom header "access-token"

Tags: regex, jmeter

I have bellow response header that is giving me the problem when extracted using  Regular Expression Extractor. To keep to story short, after troubleshooting I come up with a solution that works but is not perfect.

## The Headers

```
Response headers:
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Vary: Origin, Accept-Encoding
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Frame-Options: DENY
X-Download-Options: noopen
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
access-token: GAbnLmcDzT4j5INPkSGwdbQzZIIFIaJoy4wBnmNUF4NEgGB11IfzTAMdqXyxIhAZ
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: access-token
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
```

## The Solution

**Regular Expression** : access-token: (.+?)\n

**Template** : $1$

Refer to below picture on why I think the solution is wrong.
Extracted token is represented by multiple variable as `result_token, result_token_g, result_token_g0, result_token_g1`:

[image]

## The Question

What is the correct Regular expression and template to get only the token.

TIA!

UPDATE:

Bellow excerpt from [Regular Expression Extractor Doc](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/UserManual/Reference/RegularExpressionExtractor) actually help me better understand this question.

> If the match number is set to a negative number, then all the possible matches in the sampler data are processed. The variables are set as follows:
>
> > refName_matchNr - the number of matches found; could be 0
> >
> > refName_n, where n = 1,2,3 etc - the strings as generated by the template
> >
> > refName_n_gm, where m=0,1,2 - the groups for match n
> >
> > refName - always set to the actual template value if a match is found, otherwise, the default value.

Comment: @RichardRP I did some additional reading of Regular Expression Extractor and indeed your answer what I need. Appreciate it if you can put it as answer instead of a comment so that I can vote on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems to me, that you are getting it right; result-token_g1 contains the intended capture, and it is replicated via your template to result-token.

Don't worry about result-token_g0; it's supposed to show the complete match: capture AND context.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
Regular Expression : access-token: (.\w*)

Template: $1$

Match No: 1

DefaultValue:  Not found
```

Comment: Thanks, it works but I am still seeing this in the debug result  "
result-token=NRvxCMWs7FwHF753juOtDyoZdA5B2k8ZE60xGOo3SiFFVtQ4XO5BEqoiQWZQ3ejL
result-token_g=1
result-token_g0=access-token: NRvxCMWs7FwHF753juOtDyoZdA5B2k8ZE60xGOo3SiFFVtQ4XO5BEqoiQWZQ3ejL
result-token_g1=NRvxCMWs7FwHF753juOtDyoZdA5B2k8ZE60xGOo3SiFFVtQ4XO5BEqoiQWZQ3ejL.  Is this normal?

Comment: You can test your regex expression on response data using ViewResultsTree Listener. Just select Regexp tester in the drop-down box at the bottom of the left-hand panel in your ViewResultsTree listener. Thank you!

Comment: Already tried the RegExp Tester but for some reason it only applies to response data but not response header. I have read some documentation about the RegExp extractor. Will update to clarify my question that probably what I did (as well as the solution that you give) is correct and seeing multiple result with appended _g is as expected.